# Kinect and OpenNI

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, kinect, openni

I am new in OpenNI. When I try OpenNI sample with Visual studio 2010 c++,
I got these errors:

```
1>kinect_first_try.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__xnContextRegisterForShutdown
1>kinect_first_try.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__xnContextAddRef
1>kinect_first_try.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__xnContextRelease
1>kinect_first_try.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__xnContextUnregisterFromShutdown
1>kinect_first_try.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__xnForceShutdown
1>kinect_first_try.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__xnInit
1>kinect_first_try.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__xnGetStatusString
1>kinect_first_try.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__xnGetRefContextFromNodeHandle
1>kinect_first_try.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__xnProductionNodeAddRef
1>kinect_first_try.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__xnProductionNodeRelease
1>kinect_first_try.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__xnCreateDepthGenerator
1>kinect_first_try.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__xnStartGeneratingAll
1>kinect_first_try.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__xnOSMemSet
1>kinect_first_try.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__xnOSFreeAligned
1>kinect_first_try.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__xnOSWasKeyboardHit
1>kinect_first_try.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__xnWaitOneUpdateAll
1>kinect_first_try.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__xnGetDepthMetaData
```

Can I get any help please?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you need to include the OpenNI.lib in the linker.
Go to Project Properties | Configuration Properties | Linker | Input | Additional dependencies.
Add OpenNI.lib